# Unable to Style ActionBar Android AppCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, android-appcompat

I've included my theme in the Manifest file. My theme's code is as follows

```
<resources>
    <!-- Activity themes -->
    <style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="Theme.Sample" parent="Theme.Base" />

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sample" >
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

All my activities inherit `ActionBarActivity`

I can't seem to change the color of my `ActionBar`. 
Please help.
 I am running this on an emulator with API 21. 

How can I style my ActionBar?

Answer (score 1):

The AppCompat v21 doesn't read any android: attributes related to the action bar:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Here we setting appcompat’s actionBarStyle -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>

    <!-- ...and here we setting appcompat’s color theming attrs -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_awesome_red</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/my_awesome_darker_red</item>

    <!-- The rest of your attributes -->
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color adding this code to your style:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
```

With colorPrimaryDark you can change the status bar color.

Take care, use colorPrimary, dont use android:colorPrimary, this last only works with 21.

All code:

```
<resources>
<!-- Activity themes -->
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="Theme.Sample" parent="Theme.Base" />

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sample" >
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>    
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this [Google Blog Post](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) for the v21 appCompat extremly helpful. It explains the usage pretty good.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by below way

Simply edit the res/values/styles.xml file of your Android project.

For example like this:

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

or by java code

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
```

Comment: The application hanged.

Comment: You have to use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar().
Also AppCompat works with a Theme.AppCompat style, not with a Holo style.